# How to create multiple vue apps in same folder

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am working on a project which has different vuejs app instances like.

```
main-project
    > app1
        > src
        > build
        -- main.js
        -- App.vue
        -- package.json
    > app2
        > src
        > build
        -- main.js
        -- App.vue
        -- package.json
    > app3
        > src
        > build
        -- main.js
        -- App.vue
        -- package.json
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

I have created these app using `vue-cli` : `vue init webpack app1` , `vue init webpack app2` and so on. When I build these apps using `webpack` I got following files

```
main-project
    > dist
        > assets
            > app1
                -- app.css
                -- vendor.js
                -- app.js
                -- manifest.js
            > app2
                -- app.css
                -- vendor.js
                -- app.js
                -- manifest.js
            > app3
                -- app.css
                -- vendor.js
                -- app.js
                -- manifest.js
        -- app1.html
        -- app2.html
        -- app3.html
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

There are 3 (or more apps..) have different components eg. **Let us say app2 is only for mobile and it has all components different in such a way that these are not used (can't be used) in other apps.**
So now as long as the no of app is less in number this approach seems ok.
But when no of apps grow in size this will create same file multiple type like package.json node_modules and so on
And this will result in increase in the project file size unnecessary.

> Now my question is how to organize this in such a way that I can use
>   same package.json and node_modules (same files across different apps)
>   from a single folder like:

```
main-project
    > apps
        > src
        > build
        -- package.json
        -- main1.js
        -- App1.vue
        -- main2.js
        -- App2.vue
        -- main3.js
        -- App3.vue
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

and after build these for production

```
main-project
    > dist
        > assets
            > app1
                -- app.css
                -- vendor.js
                -- app.js
                -- manifest.js
            > app2
                -- app.css
                -- vendor.js
                -- app.js
                -- manifest.js
            > app3
                -- app.css
                -- vendor.js
                -- app.js
                -- manifest.js
        -- app1.html
        -- app2.html
        -- app3.html
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are using `webpack` template for generating boilerplate for our project in `vue-cli` we can do this in the simple way:

Just add the following code in the plugin section in `webpack.prod.conf.js` file :

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'app1.html',
      template: 'app1_template.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['app1', "vendor", "manifest"],
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'app2.html',
      template: 'app2_template.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['app2', "vendor", "manifest"],
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
```

and so....on

Answer (score 3):

Webpack can specify multiple entry files so you should be able to keep your project structure with one package.json at the root level and Webpack can build each independent file into one file.

Example Webpack

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
require('babel-loader');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        App1: './App1/main.js',
        App2: './App2/main.js'
},
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    esModule: true,
                    loaders: {
                        'js': 'babel-loader'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
        , new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './App1/*.css' },
            { from: './App1/*.html' },
            { from: './App2/*.css' },
            { from: './App2/*.html' },
        ])
    ],
    output: {
        filename: './Apps/[name]/[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    }
}
```

Comment: It somehow solves the problems but it's not as per the `webpack` template. I did little re-search and found simple solution: =>> https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/218#issuecomment-183066602

Answer (score 3):

I used the [Vue Cli Pages](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages).

```js
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    app1: {
      entry: 'src/app1/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'App1.html',
      title: 'App number one',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'rather-than-package-json', 'index'],
    },
    app2: {
      entry: 'src/app2/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'App2.html',
      title: 'App number tow',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'any-other-chunk', 'index'],
    },
    //...
  },
  //...
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to export to different directories with pages? Such as dist/app1 and dist/app2 in your case...